# Unable to find the correct xpath for input field?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng

Unable to locate the element.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   <label class="radio-inline">
   <input type="radio" name="routing_option" data-ng-model="generateRoutes" 
   data-ng-value="'manual'" class="ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched ng- 
   dirty" value="manual" style=""> Customized Routes </label>
 </div>
```

could you, help to find the xpath for value="manual"

Comment: Please add the html code that contains your element, and format your post. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the "Value" is your attribute name and it "manual" is unique for this attribute across the page.
You can use the below line to identify the element

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@value='manual']"))
```

Hope it helped